# Constructor without new C#

Tags: c#, constructor

I wonder how I could write this type of constructors:

```
Person p = Person.CreateWithName("pedro");
Person p1 = Person.CreateEmpty();
```

And having the code of each constructor in separate.

Comment: It's a static method. `public static Person CreateWithName(string name) { return new Person() { ... }; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it like this:

```
  public class Person {
    // Private (or protected) Constructor to ensure using factory methods
    private Person(String name) { 
      if (null == name)
        name = "SomeDefaultValue";

      //TODO: put relevant code here
    }

    // Factory method, please notice "static"
    public static Person CreateWithName(String name) {
      return new Person(name); 
    }

    // Factory method, please notice "static"
    public static Person CreateEmpty() {
      return new Person(null); 
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Those are so called factory methods and technically are static methods on the Class (person) that are then called on the class (Person.Create).

Technically they internally create the Person with new - but it can happen with a PRIVATE CONSTRUCTOR.

Answer (score 5):

You just create a static method inside that class, i.e.

```
class Person {
  public Person(string name) {
    //Constructor logic
  }
  public static Person CreatePerson() {
    return new Person(string.Empty);
  }
}
```